# xlwings api is missing on fresh install

Tags: python, xlwings

I'm trying to access some of the xlwings api features like

`sht.api.Copy()` and  `rng.api.Validation.add()`

raises

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Applications/PyCharm CE
>   2018.2 EAP.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_exec2.py", line 3, in Exec
>       exec(exp, global_vars, local_vars)   File "", line 1, in    File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aeosa/appscript/reference.py",
>   line 577, in **getattr**
>       raise AttributeError("Unknown property, element or command: {!r}".format(name)) from e AttributeError: Unknown property, element
>   or command: 'Copy'

I don't see those Copy() Validation in the api. autocomplete.

I tried `pip install appscript`

> Requirement already satisfied: appscript in
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (1.0.1)

So now I'm stuck. 
Seeing this on two computers both with fresh installs of 0.11 but xlwings is working fine. I have not ever used or installed older versions of xlwings.

Edit after 1 month: also asked here https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/934

Comment: What version of Office are you using on your machine. With that path, are you using MacOS?

Comment: MacOS version 10.13.6.  Excel 2016 for Mac V16.15